# map 464360 image files to read and create a tuple elixir

Tags: elixir

I have a directory as

```
/storage/hornb-vtamg
```

and it has almost `464360` jpeg files. I am trying to upload those files through an HTTP request.

this is snippet I wrote

```
defmodule Uploader do
  @root_dir "/storage"

  require Logger
  import Commons

  def start(from, to) do

    uploading = fn (tuple) ->
      upload(tuple)
    end

    dir = @root_dir <> "/" <> from <> "/"
    stream_it(dir, to)
    |> Task.async_stream(&(uploading.(&1)), max_concurrency: System.schedulers_online() * 2, timeout: :infinity)
    |> Stream.run
  end

  defp upload(%{
    timestamp: timestamp,
    image: image,
    camera_exid: camera_exid})
  do
    seaweedfs_save(camera_exid, timestamp, image)
  end
  defp upload([]), do: :noop

  defp stream_it(dir, to) do
    File.ls!(dir)
    |> Enum.map(&compose(&1, dir, to))
  end

  defp compose("CURRENT", _dir, _to), do: []
  defp compose(file, dir, to) do
    timestamp =
      String.split(file, ".")
      |> List.first
      |> Calendar.DateTime.Parse.unix!
      |> Calendar.DateTime.to_erl
      |> Calendar.DateTime.from_erl!("Europe/Dublin")
      |> Calendar.DateTime.shift_zone!("Etc/UTC")
      |> Calendar.DateTime.Format.unix
    image = File.read!(dir <> file)
    %{
      timestamp: timestamp,
      image: image,
      camera_exid: to
    }
  end
end
```

I have run this for the past 3 hours. It still didn't get out of `stream_it`, Is there a way possible to make this faster? It's just read the file and map and it's still taking that much time?

I am running this process on a machine which has

- CPU Intel® Xeon® E5-1650 v3 Hexa-Core Haswell
- RAM 256 GB DDR4 ECC

Comment: If I'm understanding your code correctly, it tries to read all the images into memory at the same time. I'm surprised you aren't OOMing. Does it help anything if you change `|> Enum.map(&compose(&1, dir, to))` to `|> Stream.map(&compose(&1, dir, to))`? I believe that would only read the images when you're ready to upload them. Also if there's a utility for doing what you're trying to do, I'd use that instead of writing your own.

Answer (score 0):

You might have a hard bottleneck of IO since you are reading so many images from the disk.
Just like brett-beatty said, using [Streams](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Stream.html)  here will do the trick, Enum module offers functions that will receive an input and output only when every input has been processed. Streams on the other hand, are lazy enumerables, input will be processed and forwarded one by one, once the first image is fetched from the file system, it will be sent to the next step.